# Pyomo Stochastic Optimization for Vehicle Routing Problem

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, stochastic

I'm trying to use the framework Pyomo in order to solve an VRP with stochastic demands. I was wondering if there is some simple examples of VRP in order to get a start point to solve it.

Any help is welcomed!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is VRP mean?

Comment: Vehicle Routing Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though my answer is late, it's better late than none.

Please visit my github page [link](https://github.com/bunmalik/svrp/)! and download the example you want.

It's similar to the ReferenceModel.py link sent earlier but that was written seven years ago and there has not been a modification to it. So I have modified it to run with the current version of pyomo.

Hope you will find it helpful